# Cron Syntax: run cron job every 10 minutes except for 10th minute

Tags: cron

I am having troubles with cron syntax,

I want to run cron job every 10 minutes,but not on 10th minute.

it has to run on 20,30,40,50,00 of the hour, not on 10.

How I do this?

`10-59/10 * * *` * doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add all times when the Job should be executed

`0,20,30,40,50 * * * *`